# CSS Classes (Help!)

Tags: css, html, class

I'm new to CSS and want to learn how to make webpages. While learning on Codecademy there was a lesson for classes and Ids which got me confused.
How should the classes be setup and does it make a difference if it's like this

```
.content h1 {

}
```

or

```
h1 .content {

}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the spaces in between the CSS selectors `.content` and `h1` matter, meaning, if you are trying to make a CSS rule specifically for `h1` elements with a class of `content`, then the rule needs to be formatted as `h1.content`.

Secondly, a CSS rule with a space in between selectors (e.g. `div .bold`) is a combinator known as a descendant selector, and in the example `div .bold { font-weight: bold; }`, it would mean that any elements with class `bold` descending from any `div` element would have a bold font weight style applied.

Answer (score 1):

`element.classname` mean you are targeting the tag having a class as classname.

`element .classname` or `.classname element` mean you are targeting the html element having class classname which is a child/descendent of tag.